# WSO2 router mediater endpoint must be in initialized

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2-esb 4.0.3 for a project. I have created several routes with end points defined. But when I send messages, sometime all the routes work fine. intermittently gets " endpoint must be initialized " and doesn't work even without any changes to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a little workaround, but I do not know, how long it work without errors. So far for this few days, my experience is "send" mediator works without above issue. So I have created a send mediator in side the router mediator, rather directly defining the target endpoint. So far the routing scanario works without error. But I do not know the implication of loads or reliability.